# Why Reads is not declared covariant?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3

Why play-json `Reads` trait is not declared covariant:

```
trait Reads[+A]
```

Related gist: https://gist.github.com/robertberry/9410272

Does covariance/contravariance interfere with implicits?

Or optionally, how to write `Reads` instance for sealed traits? https://gist.github.com/phadej/c60912802dc494c3212b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be covariant, especially when you view `Reads[A]` as just a richer form of `JsValue => A`.

But....*implicitness*.

`Reads[A]` is not only just **a** way to convert from `JsValue` to `A`, it is **the** way.

So if we had

```
sealed trait Foo
case class Bar(a: Int)
case class Baz(b: Int)
```

If you defined a `Reads[Bar]`, you would also (with covariance) have a `Reads[Foo]`.

This could be a bit weird.

```
object Foo {
  implicit reads: Reads[Foo] =
    implicitly[Reads[Bar]].orElse[implicitly[Reads[Baz]]]
}
object Bar {
  implicit reads = Json.reads[Bar] // {"a":0}
}
object Baz {
  implicit reads = Json.reads[Baz] // {"b":0}

  def blah(jsValue: JsValue): Foo = jsValue.as[Foo]
}
object Main {
  def blah(jsValue: JsValue): Foo = jsValue.as[Foo]
}
```

What is happening in `Baz.blah` and `Main.blah`? The former uses `Baz.reads`, and the latter uses `Foo.reads`, because of (complicated) implicit resolution order.

This is an edge case, and I still think you could make a good argument for covariance, but it does show the difference between "the thing can possibly parse JSON into `Foo`" and "the thing that can parse JSON into all possible `Foo`".

Comment: Thanks, the implicits is the case, as I thought. Can you comment on the gist. What's your opinion, should one write `reads[Child].map(x => x)` or `reads[Child].as[Reads[Parent]]`, can something wrong happen in the latter?

Comment: @phadej, do you mean `.asInstanceOf`? In any case, I don't think there is anything bad with expanding the type. The only problem is if it is done for implicits automatically.

Answer (score 8):

Suppose `Reads` were covariant. I've got a simple type hierarchy:

```
sealed trait Foo { def name: String }
case class Bar(name: String, i: Int) extends Foo
case class Baz(name: String, c: Char) extends Foo
```

And a `Reads` instance for one of the case classes:

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json._

implicit val readsBar: Reads[Bar] = (
  (__ \ 'name).read[String] and (__ \ 'i).read[Int]
)(Bar.apply _)
```

But `Bar <: Foo`, so `Reads[Bar] <: Reads[Foo]`, and this makes no sense—I haven't said anything about how to decode a `Baz`, so I clearly don't actually have a `Reads[Foo]`.

A better question might be why `Reads` isn't contravariant.

Comment: But if I have non-implicit `readsBar: Reads[Bar]`, and `readsBaz: Reads[Baz]`: then `readsFoo = readsBar orElse readsBaz` doesn't work. However `readsFoo = readsBar.map(x => x) orElse readsBaz.map(x => x)` is ok. Here I see covariant maps.

Comment: This still bothers me, I wrote a small gist to hopefully clarify the problem: https://gist.github.com/phadej/c60912802dc494c3212b

Comment: I don't this explanation is quite sufficient. You still have a way of translating JSON into `Foo`, so in that way, `Reads[Bar]` *is* a `Reads[Foo]`.

Comment: Making Reads contravariant makes no sense whatsoever. It would imply that a Reads[Foo] is also a Reads[Bar] and a Reads[Baz].